# capturing system diagnostics in iphone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone

I found a bug in IOS 10.X version and reported it. But apple team asked to share system diagnostics. How to capture system diagnostics  for my Iphone 5S. I searched internet But no luck. I use windows machine,(just in case if i need to install any tools).

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Privacy > Analytics`

Comment: I can see some log files, I tried uploading those file  but they rejected it :(